# my table contain data in below format and does not contain any automated primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, split

My table named `color_code` looks like this:

```
color_id      color_name
---------     ----------
101           (red,blue,green)
102           (cyan,magenta)
103           (white,deep,light,yellow)
104           (null)
```

But My data should be in below format and this resultant data should inserted into `color_insert` table

This should be my output:

```
color_id        color_name
---------       ------------
101              red
101              blue
101              green
102              cyan
102              magenta
103              white
103              deep
103              light
103              yellow
104
```

I have tried this, but not satisfied with my logic. Could you please help me on this

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..4
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO color_insert
      SELECT color_id,
             TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(color_name, '[^,]+', 1, i)) color_name
        FROM color_test 
        CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(color_id, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY color_id;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: I understand your wish, comma separated values is a mess and should never be allowed in a table.

Comment: how we will achieve below format data in sql or plsql

Comment: Maybe try and add another field that becomes your primary key, for example `color_code_id`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: See [**Split comma delimited strings in a table in Oracle**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-in-oracle/)

Comment: I posted an answer in the duplicate post that will almost exactly fit your needs if you change the table and field names.